# Scroll to move Leaflet map

Tags: javascript, scroll, mouseevent, leaflet

I've been trying different tactics to make a Leaflet-powered map pan on scrolling in the same way as it does on dragging, instead of zooming it. I could do this via a higher-level DOM API, listening to scroll events and setting center, but it neither felt good, nor was it comparable to the smoothness of dragging the map. Is there any way to move the map around by scrolling which would feel as smooth as it does by dragging?

Answer (score 2):

You could adapt the [`L.Map.ScrollWheelZoom`](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/v1.0.0-rc.3/src/map/handler/Map.ScrollWheelZoom.js) handler to perform a map pan instead of a zoom.

```js
L.Map.ScrollWheelPan = L.Map.ScrollWheelZoom.extend({
  _performZoom: function() {
    var map = this._map,
      delta = this._delta;

    map.stop(); // stop panning and fly animations if any

    delta = delta > 0 ? Math.ceil(delta) : Math.floor(delta);
    delta = Math.max(Math.min(delta, 4), -4);

    this._delta = 0;
    this._startTime = null;

    if (!delta) {
      return;
    }

    map.panBy([0, -delta * 40]); // Adjust 40 to your feeling.
  }
});

L.Map.addInitHook('addHandler', 'scrollWheelPan', L.Map.ScrollWheelPan);

var map = L.map("map", {
  scrollWheelZoom: false,
  scrollWheelPan: true
});
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/3v7hd2vx/67/

Comment: Your solution only allows to scroll up or down, but using `Event#wheelDeltaX` and `Event#wheelDeltaY`, it's possible to make it pan on scrolling in any direction, and it feels very smooth. Thanks for your idea, it helped a lot!

Comment: @rishat could you share your final solution? I don't really understand where to use wheelDeltaX/Y

Answer (score 0):

Not enough reputation to comment, made a spinoff of ghybs's fiddle incorporating my interpretation of Rishat's comment: [XY scrolling on Leaflet](https://jsfiddle.net/raphaelrk/5u3xdqxe/1/)

```
// based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38898519/scroll-to-move-leaflet-map

let m = document.querySelectorAll('#map')[0];

L.DomEvent.on(m, 'wheel', function(e) {
  let x = e.deltaX;
  let y = e.deltaY;

  map.stop();
  map.panBy([x, y]);
})

L.Map.ScrollWheelPan = L.Map.ScrollWheelZoom.extend({
  _performZoom: function() {}
});

L.Map.addInitHook('addHandler', 'scrollWheelPan', L.Map.ScrollWheelPan);

var map = L.map("map", {
  scrollWheelZoom: false,
  scrollWheelPan: true
});
L.tileLayer("//stamen-tiles-{s}.a.ssl.fastly.net/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg").addTo(map);

map.setView([48.85, 2.35], 3);
```